# TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple TROUBLES

Tags: python

[I only used the snipping too instead of ctrl V be this website was displaying my incorrectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFTcX.png) so I am trying to make some code for a project, this codes goal is to grab each individual word from (word) and assign it to a var in (var). but i get the error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

I am a beginner so I  don't get why it is telling me this and I do not know what is causing this. I do not want it to be a tuple, but if there is an easier way to fix this using a tuple, that I have open ears. This error is occurring on line 26.

Comment: Which line is the error occurring on?

Comment: edited to show now

Comment: Hey, I stumbled upon this question by accident. In StackOverflow when someone has succesfully answered your question you can `mark` it as answered. You can do so like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png Accepting someones answer will help them and it helps others find answers more easily

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to create over 20 variables all representing different words. If you iterate over the words, you don't need to create so many variables. Try this example, and you will get a list of words from the string.

Try this example:

```
weirdString = '-this---is-------a---string---about-apartheid------'
words = [word for word in weirdString.split('-') if word != '']
for word in words:
    print(words)
```

Then if you want the index of the word, you can use `enumerate()`

```
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    print(word, i)
```

Comment: I will try this code, and see if this gives me the expected result

Comment: my project requires me to input this onto a scrabble like a board, one by one, so I need the code I made to make separate lines, input them, and press enters, and do other processes. I need it to do that a few times over with different words

Comment: The edits you did are useful, I do not have a vast knowledge of python so I did not know any of that

Comment: No problem! Accept my answer if it works for you. Good luck learning my friend!

Comment: I guess I have one more question. would there be a way to leave the (-) and remove all the letters, I want the (-) to be separated based on if they are being separated by words

Comment: before("we---are--cool----')                                                                                   after("---", "--","----")

Comment: Yes, iterate through the words in the list and string.strip() them from the original string.

Comment: is there a way to split all letters?

Comment: look into re (regular expressions) https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html, and accept my answer if it worked for you :)